# Checking Facebook user login status

Tags: facebook

I have a web site. i do it using PHP. In home page i want to check if a user is still logged / or not into facebook.

if facebook session is available  alert("OK") otherwise alert("No")

I have tried this code but it not working for me

```
<html> 
<head> 

</head>

<body> 
<script>
function logged() {
    alert('logged');
}
function notlogged() {
    alert('not logged');
}
</script>
<script src="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/composer/attachment/question/question.php" onload="logged()" onerror="notlogged()">
</body> 
</html>
```

when after i logged out from facebook this code alert as logged.

what is wrong with this code?

thanks

best regards;
thari

Answer (score 4):

This code does nothing. There is no way this code would ever do anything useful.

Comment: Not an answer, although you're right.

Comment: @AlexLunix Bullshit. The question is "what is wrong with this code?" The answer is "everything".

Comment: Touché, I've retracted the -1.

Comment: Thank you, that's appreciated. :-)

Comment: please help me to correct this code to solve my problem-thanks

Comment: @Thari There's really no correcting this code, it does nothing. This isn't a "write my code for me" sort of site.